# Error in combining two queries in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write query for this problem :

Write a query to select only those books whose all authors belong to Indian Nationality.

wherein

I am trying to combine two queries using inner join but it is giving a error..

My query is ..

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (books_authors 
WHERE books_authors.author_id IN 
        (
           SELECT author_id 
           FROM obl_authors WHERE nationality='Indian' 
        )  GROUP BY books_authors.book_id) A

INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM books_authors 
    GROUP BY books_authors.book_id 
) B
ON A=B
```

Its giving this error :

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL    server version for the right syntax to use near 'where books_authors.author_id in (select author_id from obl_authors where nation' at line 1
```

I have 3 tables obl_books,obl_authors and books_authors(link table)..what i am trying to do here is in 1st query i am retrieving row counts of author_id where nationality is indian from obl_author table for each book_id

In second query iam retriving row counts of all authors of a particular book_id.

And i want to combine these two queries to check the count of rows of author_id of a book_id is equal to its total row count(that iam retrieving from second query)..if it is then retrieve that book_id.

In the ON clause I did A=B to check its equality but how would i tell it to even retrieve those book_ids if it matches (i.e A=B)

Answer (score 0):

You have to join these on some column like this:

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM    
    (SELECT COUNT(*), books_authors.book_id FROM (books_authors WHERE books_authors.author_id IN (SELECT author_id FROM obl_authors WHERE nationality='Indian' ) GROUP BY books_authors.book_id) A

    INNER JOIN 

    (SELECT COUNT(*), books_authors.book_id FROM books_authors GROUP BY books_authors.book_id ) B

    ON A.book_id = B.book_id
```

To check if it is equal in count you actually do not need to join the tables, because you have just plain number, so you do like this:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*), books_authors.book_id FROM (books_authors WHERE books_authors.author_id IN (SELECT author_id FROM obl_authors WHERE nationality='Indian' ))
    -
    (SELECT COUNT(*), books_authors.book_id FROM books_authors)
```

Comment: No its not working ..and I want to check if the count of those 2 queries are equal, not their book_ids

Comment: If your selects do work separately, then this query should be working too. As for your request... I updated my answer. However, grouping by then has no logic since you are not using the column you grouped on... The grouping will return more than one row possibly, so there is no way you will be able to subtract the counts to check if they are equal. Either you group on the key and compare inside each pair, or you don't group at all :)

Answer (score 0):

You're not a million miles away from the correct answer; you just need to—

1. Create an outer query that selects the `book_id` from the result of joining your two subqueries;
2. Move the opening parenthesis of your `A` subquery to the start of its subquery;
3. Include `book_id` in the select lists of each subquery; and
4. Join on both `book_id` and the counts (I use a `NATURAL JOIN` in my example below).

Thus:

```
SELECT book_id FROM (
  SELECT   book_id, COUNT(*)
  FROM     books_authors 
  WHERE    author_id IN (
             SELECT author_id 
             FROM   obl_authors
             WHERE  nationality='Indian' 
           )
  GROUP BY book_id
) A NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   book_id, COUNT(*)
  FROM     books_authors 
  GROUP BY book_id 
) B
```

However, one can actually get there much more simply by using a filter in the `HAVING` clause of a simple join between the tables:

```
SELECT   b.book_id
FROM     books_authors b
    JOIN obl_authors   a USING (author_id)
GROUP BY b.book_id
HAVING   SUM(a.nationality='Indian') = COUNT(*)
```

Comment: But can you please explain how natural join alone worked in ur 1st answer for getting those book_ids where count of both subquery is equal.. I thought there should come some equality condition..I am new to sql ..so kindly explain..

Comment: @aarti: `NATURAL JOIN` simply requires that all identically named columns on each side of the join have identical values.  It's the same as saying `USING (book_id, \`COUNT(*)\`)` or `ON A.book_id=B.book_id AND A.\`COUNT(*)\` = B.\`COUNT(*)\`` (although in the latter case the join will result in two columns named `book_id` and two named `COUNT(*)`, so the `book_id` in the select list will be ambiguous without a table qualifier, whereas in the other cases there will only be one each of those columns).

Comment: @aarti: Why are you "*unable to add any table name in from clause of outer query*" ?